# getting editText input from PopUpWindow

Tags: android

I was wondering how I could get the input from an editText box in a popupwindow. I tried 2 ways. One with a layout inflator and one without but I either get "" or null even though i typed something into the box

This one returns the "" :

```
// get the username and password inputs
        View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.login_popup, null);
        EditText usernameInput = (EditText) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.username_login_input);
        EditText passwordInput = (EditText) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.password_login_input);

        final String usernameString = usernameInput.getText().toString();
        final String passwordString = passwordInput.getText().toString();
```

This one returns null :

```
// get the username and password inputs
        EditText usernameInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_login_input);
        EditText passwordInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_login_input);

        final String usernameString = usernameInput.getText().toString();
        final String passwordString = passwordInput.getText().toString();
```

I am trying to get it from login_popup.xml which is not generated from an activity

This is where the code is from

**EDIT**

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = 
                 (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.login_popup, null);
        ppw = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
        ViewGroup parentLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.title_page_layout);
        // set the position and size of popup
        ppw.showAtLocation(parentLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 10, 20);
```

Comment: Please post some more code for context. Where does this code appear? In an AlertDialog? In a DialogFragment?

Comment: You can edit your post...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following instead when your popup window is closed:

```
View contentView = ppw.getContentView();
EditText usernameInput = (EditText) contentView.findViewById(R.id.username_login_input);
EditText passwordInput = (EditText) contentView.findViewById(R.id.password_login_input);
final String usernameString = usernameInput.getText().toString();
final String passwordString = passwordInput.getText().toString();
```

I think your current approach is inflating new views, rather than obtaining the existing views from the popup window.